# Is there a performance penalty when using security-enabled services in ArcGIS Server?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, performance

I enabled security on our installation of ArcGIS Server last week, and modified an existing application of ours to use the service tokens to access the services.  The application works with the new services, but the performance feels...slower.  I'm not sure how else to describe it.  Is there a performance penalty when using secure services?  Has anyone using secure services had to do any additional performance tuning after enabling security.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using fiddler to compare traffic between secured and non-secured web services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it just token based security? or are there other things enabled like HTTPS?

It probably is a little slower since it has to verify who you are now, but the best way to test it would be to use fiddle or firebug to compare the traffic response times.

Comment: what would be the best method to test this?  Ideally I would test against an identical service, one secure and one public, right?